# vba treeview to show count against each selection

Tags: excel, vba

I want to show the count of cources in tree view against each selection. Please advise if it is possible.

```
Hea Manager DM      Cources
AMP Diwaar  Dsameer kap 5   5
AMP Diwaar  Dsameer Danke   4
AMP Diwaar  Vishaws Bhagan  9
AMP Rohan   Sapla   Kumbar  5
AMP Rohan   Sapla   Dhaval  7
AMP Abhiji  t Maoj  Khalsa  5
AMP Abhiji  t hiral Rajiwa  8
AMP Abhiji  t hiral Shitol  9
AMP Chande  kar Atul Gunjal 10
AMP Chande  kar Atul Gundad 5
AMP Chande  kar Gsame ePa   6
AMP Dhanes  ssGa    nesKh   3
AMP Dhanes  ssGa    nesKe   5
AMP Dhanes  sssu    haiDa   8
AMP Dhanes  sssu    haiNi   9
```

(code so far)

```
Set rTWData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D16")
With TreeView1
    Set oNode = .Nodes.Add(, , "root", "+")
    oNode.Expanded = True

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each oRow In rTWData.Rows
        .Nodes.Add "root", tvwChild, oRow.Cells(1, 1).Value, oRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
        .Nodes.Add oRow.Cells(1, 1).Value, tvwChild, oRow.Cells(1, 2).Value, oRow.Cells(1, 2).Value
        .Nodes.Add oRow.Cells(1, 2).Value, tvwChild, oRow.Cells(1, 3).Value, oRow.Cells(1, 3).Value
        .Nodes.Add oRow.Cells(1, 3).Value, tvwChild, oRow.Cells(1, 4).Value, oRow.Cells(1, 4).Value

    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Take look in that example:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
Call Tworzenie_treeview_w_locie 
End Sub 

Private Sub Tworzenie_treeview_w_locie() 
Dim lvw As Object 
Dim ctl As Control 
Set ctl = UserForm1.Controls.Add("MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2", "TreeView1") 
With ctl 
    .Left = 0 
    .Top = 0 
    Me.Height = 205:    .Height = Me.Height 
    Me.Width = 350:     .Width = Me.Width 
    .Visible = True 
End With 
    Set lvw = ctl 

With lvw 
    .Nodes.Clear 
    .LineStyle = 1 
    Dim nodX As Object 
    With .Nodes 
        Set nodX = .Add(Key:="ADMINISTRATOR", Text:="ADMINISTRATOR") 
            nodX.ForeColor = vbRed 
        .Add Relative:="ADMINISTRATOR", relationship:=4, Key:="EF1", Text:="Posiadają wszelkie prawa" 
        .Add Relative:="EF1", relationship:=4, Key:="EF1a", Text:="Ograniczenie co do wykonywania kopii forum" 
        .Add Relative:="EF1", relationship:=4, Key:="EF1b", Text:="Ograniczenie co do wjazdu do FTP" 
        .Add Relative:="EF1", relationship:=4, Key:="EF1c", Text:="Ograniczenie co do publikacji reklam" 

        Set nodX = .Add(Key:="MODERATOR", Text:="MODERATOR") 
            nodX.ForeColor = vbGreen 
                   .Add Relative:="MODERATOR", relationship:=4, Key:="EF2a", Text:="Prawa do usunięcia postów" 
        Set nodX = .Add(Relative:="MODERATOR", relationship:=4, Key:="EF2b", Text:="Prawa modyfikacji postów") 
        Set nodX = .Add(Relative:="MODERATOR", relationship:=4, Key:="EF2c", Text:="Prawa do przesunięcia postów") 

        Set nodX = .Add(Key:="VIP", Text:="VIP") 
            nodX.ForeColor = vbBlue 
                   .Add Relative:="VIP", relationship:=4, Key:="EF3", Text:="Wzór do naśladowania dla nowych forumowiczów" 
                   .Add Relative:="EF3", relationship:=4, Key:="EF3a", Text:="Trzewienie dobrych zwyczajów" 
        Set nodX = .Add(Relative:="EF3", relationship:=4, Key:="EF3b", Text:="Dbanie o poprawny język") 
            nodX.ForeColor = vbBlue 
                   .Add Relative:="VIP", relationship:=4, Key:="EF4", Text:="Prawa do przesunięcia postów" 
                   .Add Relative:="EF4", relationship:=4, Key:="EF4a", _ 
                        Text:="Odpowiednie umieszczenie to łątwiejsze odszukaanie odpowiedzi" 
    End With 
End With 
Set ctl = Nothing 
Set lvw = Nothing 
End Sub
```

This is how you can do "it on the fly", but the same rules works when you coll object by name